# ios 9.1 farsi font (specially byekan)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9.1

In iOS 9.1 all the apps with byekan font has got problems, does anyone know is this the iOS bug or anything wrong in code?

sample on iOS 9.1: [image: Link]

sample on iOS 8.1.3: [image: Link]

Comment: @robmayoff I added the correct form on ios 8

Comment: Please also add the text as text that I can copy and paste into a test program.

Comment: (گارانتی یک ماه تعویض + ۱۸ ماه گارانتی مایکروتل (نماینده رسمی سامسونگ در ایران

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Have a same problem after upgrading to iOS 9.1, searching forums didn't help me and there is no trick to solving this. there is no source from apple why Persian font's like (B Fonts) have problem.

finally I found X Fonts which is similar to B Fonts, except that they are ok in iOS 9.1

you can find them at:
[persian fonts for mac](http://irfont.ir/post/113/Persian-fonts-for-macintoush)

Comment: these X fonts solve my problem BUT another problem appears: farsi numbers are shown in english, do you have any solution for this?